# Add bar button to navigation bar programatically

Tags: ios, swift

I want to when I click to the button, it will present a navigation bar. But the button that I add, it doesn't show.

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func handleCommentsCountButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    let navigation = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: navigation, action: "backAction")
    navigation.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton

    self.presentViewController(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
```

Comment: Can you try `navigation.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem`?

Comment: Nice, it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding answer since I could not find a duplicate of this question.

You can use this:

```
navigation.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Answer (score 1):

`navigationItem` is a UIViewController property and Apple's documentation for `navigationItem` says

> Created on-demand so that a view controller may customize its
>   navigation appearance.

Which means the correct place to set navigation item buttons is in respective view controllers.
So you should be setting the navigation item buttons on

```
    loginVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

or directly in `LoginViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` as

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

The suggested comment and answer using `topItem` works because topItem indirectly gives access to the top view controller's navigation item.